# Ionic - How to remove sidemenu on login page only?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to remove sidemenu only on my login page. Otherwise remain. How it can be done? I'm using command ionic `ionic start myApp sidemenu` to create the project.

app.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })

    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('app.search', {
      url: "/search",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/search.html"
        }
      }
    })
```

login page

```
<ion-view title="Login">
  <ion-content>
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item">
          <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" ng-click="login()">Log in</button>
        </label>
      </div>

  </ion-content>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try this http://plnkr.co/edit/3k0JeK2Zxwbo3D6kGr4L?p=preview

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can disable/enable sidemenu at any time at any page by calling

**`$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false)`**

e.g:

```
angular.module('ABC').controller('xyzCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false)

});
```

Comment: The main thing is not to forget on leaving view enable menu. `$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function () {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true)
    });`

Answer (score 14):

```
**Ionic 2**


    import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

    export class LoginPage {

       constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController) {

       }

       ionViewWillEnter() {

           this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable( false )
       }

       ionViewDidLeave() {

           this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable( true )
       }
    }



IONIC 4: Sept2019
try this code to in your login.page.ts
Step1: import {  MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
Step2: constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController) { }
(below constructo)
Step3: ionViewWillEnter() {
          this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
       }
       ionViewDidLeave() {
          this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
       } 

this code will help you to work with side menu flawlessly on any screen, if you login & re-login and try it will work now.
```

Comment: thankyou! For anyone else who does a ctrl+f on this massive page: ionic2 ionic3 ionic 3.

Comment: This is working but the main issue when i have login ,register and other screen as well. at that time it is not working.

Comment: @Anuj try to change `ionViewWillEnter` to `ionViewDidEnter` and `ionViewDidLeave` to `ionViewWillLeave`, because in your case, I think that previous page is enabling swipe after your actual page is disabling it. You can debug it with console logs next to each swipeEnable call, to see the order of calls.

Comment: Why didn't my *ngIf="currentUser != null" work, even though it renders {{ currentUser | json }} showing null, it would not update the ngIf until I refreshed the page? Is something up with Ionic for that?

Answer (score 12):

same issue here. just add hide-nav-bar="true" to the ion-view

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: But if the user drags from left to right (or the opposite) the menu is still shown.

Comment: No, it doesn't shown.
But if it shows you can handler the swipe, if it's necesary.

Comment: if menu is showing when drag than disable it by  $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false); in login controller

Answer (score 9):

What you can do is define the login page without a sidemenu. Check your login page HTML template. Make sure you do not have the `<ion-side-menus>` and `<ion-side-menu>` elements in it. These are used on pages that need to have a sidemenu.

Your login page should look like this:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
     <!--your page content goes in here-->
   </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

To have sidemenu on other pages, just put the sidemenu content in a parent state which in your code is the `app` state.

Your menu.html file:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu>
      <!--put your side menu content here-->
      <!--any child state of app will inherit this sidemenu-->
    </ion-side-menu>

   <ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
   </ion-side-menu-content>
  </ion-side-menus>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I've asked a question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080849/ionic-showing-side-menu-only-in-concrete-pages
I'm not really achieving the results I want. Find some of the ionic documentation weak or insuficient :-/

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the game but this is another option for those (like me) who need to keep their login view within the `side-menu` layout but need to hide the side menu button while keeping the view title.

Inside the `login.html` view use the `ion-header-bar` directive to create a new header with a title and then hide the `ion-nav-bar` in the `side-menu` layout via the `ion-view` tag.

**Example (login.html)**

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="center">
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
 <!-- Login content goes here -->
</ion-view>
```

Then if you need to disable any drag gestures do so in the controller like @waqas suggests.

Answer (score 5):

I have made a small demo for the question.

**[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/uX5db7Cnf2IAZZTNaHDq?p=preview)**

If you want a page differently from sidemenu.Create a new `Parent state`.
For example

```
$stateProvider
    .state('landing', {
        url: '/landing',
        controller: 'landingCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'landing.html'
    });
```

**Html :**

```
<ion-view class="view-bg-blue" >
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="openMenu()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content padding="true">
        <h3 class="text-center">Welcome To Landing Page</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h4>My App</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input placeholder="User">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input placeholder="password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right button-calm" ng-click="open()">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Then call this state using `/landing` when ever you want.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late but here is a quick and easy solution.

Add this in your login Controller

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(event) {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
});
//enable side menu drag before moving to next view
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function(event) {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-side-menus>
```

bcn

```
            <ion-tab title="ALL" href="#/dashbord/all" class="bgorange">
                <ion-nav-view name="all"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>


            <ion-tab title="INFO" class="bgorange" href="#/dashbord/info">
                <ion-nav-view name="info"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab title="EVENTS" class="bgorange" href="#/dashbord/events">
                <ion-nav-view name="events"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>


        </ion-tabs>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

    </ion-pane>
    <div ng-include src="calender.html"></div>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">

        <ion-content has-header="true">
            <ion-list>

                <ion-item menu-close class="item-icon-left bottombordernone" href="#/dashbord">
                    <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
                    What's New
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close class="item-icon-left bottombordernone">
                    <i class="icon ion-chatbox-working"></i>
                    Feedback
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close class="item-icon-left bottombordernone" ng-click="logout()">
                    <i class="icon ion-power"></i>
                    Logout
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
```

@Zulu here's my full code.
I hope this Ex. work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// index.html
<body>
  <section ui-view></section>
</body>

// routes.js
$stateProvider
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login')
```

it's work, see more here: [angular-ui/ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

You have to watch the slide menu.
If it is open, you have to toggle it and close.

```
 .controller('kayTOlCtrl', function($scope,$ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
     //
     $scope.$watch(function () {
            return $ionicSideMenuDelegate.getOpenRatio();
        },

                    function (ratio) {
                        if (ratio != 0) {
                          $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();

                        }

                    });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false) does disable the ability to swipe to access the menu, but does not hide the hamburger toggle button in the navbar (if you have one).  To do that, you can use ng-show with $root binding in your ion-side-menu-content element like this:

```
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"
      ng-show="$root.showMenuIcon">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
```

Then in your login controller:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event) {
  $scope.$root.showMenuIcon = false;
  $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
});

$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function (event) {
  $scope.$root.showMenuIcon = true;
  $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also add this to your main app controller:

```
$scope.$root.enableLeft = true;
$scope.$root.showMenuIcon = true;
```

and simply switch it to false in every controller you dont want your side menu appear in:

```
$scope.$root.enableLeft = false;
$scope.$root.showMenuIcon = false;
```

add is-enabled="$root.enableLeft" to your  html tag and ng-show="$root.showMenuIcon" to the button inside  html tag.

Answer (score 0):

Based on various answers here from everyone and 15 minutes of trying, here is my working example of it, and it should work as simply doing copy-paste

Your view, like login.html

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-light title-image" align-title="center">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Your related controller, like LoginCtrl

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(event) {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
    });
    //enable side menu drag before moving to next view
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function(event) {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'templates/loginpage.html'
    })
.state('app.account', {
        url: '/account',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/account.html',
                controller: 'AccountCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {IonicApp, Page, NavController, MenuController} from 'ionic/ionic';
import {TabsPage} from '../tabs/tabs';
import {SignupPage} from '../signup/signup';
import {UserData} from '../../providers/user-data';


@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  constructor(nav: NavController, userData: UserData, menu: MenuController) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.userData = userData;

    this.login = {};
    this.submitted = false;

    this.menu = menu;

  }

  onLogin(form) {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (form.valid) {
      this.userData.login();
      this.nav.push(TabsPage);
    }
  }

  onSignup() {
    this.nav.push(SignupPage);
  }

  onPageDidEnter() {
    // the left menu should be disabled on the login page
    this.menu.enable(false);
  }

  onPageDidLeave() {
    // enable the left menu when leaving the login page
    this.menu.enable(true);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
       <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
           <h1 class="title">Cards</h1>
       </ion-header-bar>
       <ion-content scroll="true">
       </ion-content>
   </ion-pane>
```

This is works for me ...

Answer (score -3):

I think the simplest solution in opening the login page in a modal view, checkout [$ionicModal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/)

Comment: Downvoted because it in no way is helpful to the person who asked the question--