# Ionic - Showing side-menu ONLY in concrete pages

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm developing an App with Ionic Framework, and I only want to show a side-menu in some concrete views, but not in every view.

I' have my **menu.html** file:

```
<ion-side-menus>

  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7">
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-pane>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">

    <ion-content class="mymenu">

      <div id="menu-list">
        <ion-list class="list">
          <ion-item item-type="item-icon-left" nav-clear menu-close href="#">
            <i class="icon ion-home"></i><span>Menu Item</span>
          </ion-item>
           ...
        </ion-list>
      </div>

    </ion-content>

  </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

My **index.html**'s *body tag* looks exactly like this:

```
 <body ng-app="myApp">
   <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
 </body>
```

And the *JavaScript* code where I set up my App states:

```
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
          url: "/app",
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
          controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })

        .state('app.page1', {
            url: "/page1",
            views: {
                'menuContent' :{
                    templateUrl: "templates/page1.html"
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.page2', {
            url: "/page2",
            views: {
                'menuContent' :{
                    templateUrl: "templates/page2.html"
                }
            }
        })

        // etc...

       // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/page1');
   });
```

**page1.html** and **page2.html** both contain the following structure:

```
<ion-view title="something">
   <ion-content>
       ... // here comes the html content of the page
   </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

What can I actually do to only show my side-menu (**menu.html**) on **page1.html** and not on **page2.html**?? Is there anything I'm missing??

Is there a way of inserting the **menu.html** content only on those pages I want it to appear and forgetting about creating the state that uses it as `templateUrl`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason why your all your pages have side menu is because you 'app' state as their parent state. When a state is activated, its templates are automatically inserted into the `<ion-view>` of its parent state's template. If it's a top-level state, because it has no parent state then its parent template is `index.html`. The `app` state has the side menu in it.

Your code should look like this:

```
config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
          url: "/app",
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
          controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })

         //this state has the 'app' state (which has the sidemenu) as its parent state
        .state('app.page1', {
            url: "/page1",
            views: {
                'menuContent' :{
                    templateUrl: "templates/page1.html"
                }
            }
        })

         //this state has no parent, so it uses 'index.html' as its template. The index page has no 
         //sidemenu in it
        .state('page2', {
            url: "/page2",
            templateUrl: "templates/page2.html"
            }
        })

         ///more code here
   });
```

Check out https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: Thank you very much Akinkunle Allen, I was suspicious about something was happening because 'app' was the parent state of every state, but didn't know how to solve it - this is my very first experience using the Ionic Framework. Regards!

Comment: Once I change the "app" state, my page starts treating index.html as the parent and stop reading what is inside the HTML i'm calling. Any idea? 

 // LOGIN 

 .state('login', {
  url: '/login',
 
  views: {
   'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
   }
  }
 })

Comment: Yes it solved the issue but it will create one more issue as the transition effect between page change will not work any more.So do you have any solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

if your problem is simple , use

```
onExit: function(){
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#menuAPP')).removeClass('hidden');
}
```

into state

Answer (score 0):

just add hide-nav-bar=" true " in ion-view

```
<ion-view title="Login" **hide-nav-bar="true"** id="page" class=" "> </ion-view>
```