# Do not want sidemenu and tabs on login page

Tags: ionic-framework

I have sidemenu template but as sidemenu is everywhere, I do not want it to display on log in untill user logs in, I hit [Ionic - How to remove sidemenu on login page only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165972/ionic-how-to-remove-sidemenu-on-login-page-only/34908973?noredirect=1#comment57557336_34908973) and see solution from @Waqas where he suggested `$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false)` so just wondering if it can working something like 

`sudo 
if user not logged in
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false)`

Comment: Post some code snippets of your login page, controller, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put it in your login page.

```
<ion-view title=""  hide-nav-bar="true">
```

and this in your menu: (userislogged is a var in your controller)

```
<div ng-if="userislogged">
    <ion-side-menu side="left" expose-aside-when="large">
    menu.... here   
    </ion-side-menu>
</div>
```

I hope this help you....