# ionic hide menu button but keep back button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on a ionic framework app, where i need to hide only menu button on a specific template but need to keep back button.

it is showing like [image: this]

My `app.js`

```
// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    cache: false,
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
  })


  .state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    cache: false,
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.models', {
      url: '/models',
      cache: false,
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/models.html',
          controller: 'ModelCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.model', {
      url: '/model/:Id',
      cache: false,
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/models-data.html',
          controller: 'ModeldataCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.models-detail', {
      url: '/models/:Id',
      cache: false,
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/single-model.html',
          controller: 'ModelDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('app.about', {
    url: '/about',
    cache: false,
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/about.html',
          controller: 'AboutCtrl'
        }
      }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');

});
```

`Menu` html is:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Rolls</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/home">
          Home
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/models">
          Models
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/about">
          About
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

single-model html page where i am getting both menu and back button code are : `single-model.html`

```
<ion-view view-title="{{models.title}}">
  <ion-content class="padding" overflow-scroll="true">
    <img ng-src="{{models.image}}" style="width: 64px; height: 64px">
    <p>
      {{models.subtitle}}
    </p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Model and single model controller code is :

```
.controller('ModeldataCtrl', function($rootScope,$scope,$ionicLoading,$timeout, $stateParams, Models) {     
      $rootScope.dataloarding();
      Models.modeldata($stateParams.Id).success(function(result){
        if(result.success =='1'){
                  $scope.modeldata = result.data;
                  $rootScope.hideloading();
                }

              })
              .error(function(result)
                     {
                      $rootScope.hideloading();
                      $rootScope.showAlert("Internet Connection Error");
              });
})

.controller('ModelDetailCtrl', function($rootScope,$scope,$ionicLoading,$timeout, $stateParams,$ionicSideMenuDelegate, Models) {
      $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
      $rootScope.dataloarding();
      Models.singlemodel($stateParams.Id).success(function(result){
        if(result.success =='1'){
                  $scope.models = result.data;
                  $rootScope.hideloading();
                }

              })
              .error(function(result)
                     {
                      $rootScope.hideloading();
                      $rootScope.showAlert("Internet Connection Error");
              });
})
```

i follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165972/ionic-how-to-remove-sidemenu-on-login-page-only) and [this](http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/driftyco/ionic/q/stackoverflow/27930702/ionic-framework-state-go39app-home39-is-adding-back-button-on-page-where-i-want) but it remove both back button and menu both or back button only.

Is there any solution to remove only menu from single-model html page only ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<ion-view view-title="Register">

  <!-- to remove sidemenu button -->
  <ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
...
```

I just added a simple nav-bar. The sidemenu button is gone and I kept the back button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it works for me. Replace your side menu content with below code

```
<ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-chevron-left"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
```